# Filter rows based on condition sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, filter

The below is the sample data.

```
Op_ID   manual  TT 
------------------
1       0       32
1       1       38.4
2       0       4.56
2       1       7.5
55      1       50
55      1       30
```

- case 1: i need to check Op_id and manual column, if the manual column is having 0 then i need to take tt value= 32 and ignore the below record. similarly needs to check the other records.i.e. op_id=2 and manual=0 then need to take tt=4.56.
- case 2: if both records having manual =1 then i need to take max of tt, i.e tt=50.(for the op_id=55).

```
So i need the output like below.
```

```
Op_ID   manual  TT 
------------------
1       0       32
2       0       4.56
55      1       50
```

Comment: Have you tried any query at all? Where are you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select opid, manual, tt
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by opid order by manual, tt desc) rn
  from yourtable ) v
where rn = 1
```